# How do I keep the imshow() window responsive even if frame processing takes several seconds?

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface

I want to implement [this](https://github.com/MayankSingal/PyTorch-Image-Dehazing) library with video dehazing ability.
I have only CPU, but I expect the result will be good without GPU,because video output of DCP,or any other dehaze algorithm works good.

So I developed this code:

```
import cv2
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import math

class dehaze_net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(dehaze_net, self).__init__()

        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    
        self.e_conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,3,1,1,0,bias=True) 
        self.e_conv2 = nn.Conv2d(3,3,3,1,1,bias=True) 
        self.e_conv3 = nn.Conv2d(6,3,5,1,2,bias=True) 
        self.e_conv4 = nn.Conv2d(6,3,7,1,3,bias=True) 
        self.e_conv5 = nn.Conv2d(12,3,3,1,1,bias=True) 
        
    def forward(self, x):
        source = []
        source.append(x)

        x1 = self.relu(self.e_conv1(x))
        x2 = self.relu(self.e_conv2(x1))

        concat1 = torch.cat((x1,x2), 1)
        x3 = self.relu(self.e_conv3(concat1))

        concat2 = torch.cat((x2, x3), 1)
        x4 = self.relu(self.e_conv4(concat2))

        concat3 = torch.cat((x1,x2,x3,x4),1)
        x5 = self.relu(self.e_conv5(concat3))

        clean_image = self.relu((x5 * x) - x5 + 1) 
        
        return clean_image

model = dehaze_net()

model.load_state_dict(torch.load('snapshots/dehazer.pth',map_location=torch.device('cpu')))

device = torch.device('cpu')
model.to(device)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame = torch.from_numpy(frame.transpose((2, 0, 1))).float().unsqueeze(0) / 255.0
        frame = frame.to(device)

        with torch.no_grad():
            dehazed_frame = model(frame).squeeze().cpu().numpy()

        dehazed_frame = (dehazed_frame * 255).clip(0, 255).transpose((1, 2, 0)).astype(np.uint8)
        dehazed_frame = cv2.cvtColor(dehazed_frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        cv2.imshow('Dehazed Frame', dehazed_frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break


cap.release()


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is a single file code that needs only `snapshots/dehazer.pth` to be downloaded from original source(*MayankSingal/PyTorch-Image-Dehazing*).
I downloaded it and executed the code.
for time being let me show a paper in camera,

#### The problem:

The problem is

1. the window that shows the video freezes until it gets a new frame, i.e: Frame1--->FREEZE--->Frame2..., Here is some example:
   [image: for 1 second the window looks good]
   for 1 second the window looks good
   [image: for 5 second the window goes not responding/hangs/freezes...]
   for 5 second the window goes not responding/hangs/freezes...
2. the window that shows the video, shows the frames with long delay, that is it takes about 5 second for a frame

I was expecting smooth live output(its fine even if Frame-Per-Second is 1 or 2), but I am not ok with that "Not responding" window, I feel the code I/Author have put has some flaw/problem/loop hole. If I use any other code, lik DCP,there is no problem. So whats the part that cause not responding, how to solve?

Comment: this is how GUI works. it needs to run the event loop (here: waitKey()) often enough. once every couple seconds is not often enough, hence the OS steps in and marks the program as unresponsive. if you want to avoid that, you could try showing your images with matplotlib. I believe that runs an event loop in the background.

Comment: if you want to stick with OpenCV, or any other GUI, really, you need to do your heavy computations __outside__ of the GUI event loop, i.e. put it into a thread. then, whenever the processing has a new image to show, you show it or pass it to the GUI loop for display (using a queue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUIs need to run their event processing regularly. If that doesn't happen often enough, the GUI becomes noticeably unresponsive. Most operating systems notice that for you and alert you about the program becoming unresponsive.

GUIs are event-based. Any intensive computations **must** be performed outside of the event loop, i.e. in a thread.

That is not the case in your program because you perform (compute-intensive) inference in the same loop that calls `waitKey()`, which is the function in OpenCV that performs GUI event processing.

Here is a brief sketch that shows how to use threads:

```py
import cv2 as cv
import threading
import queue


def worker_function(stop_event, result_queue):
    cap = cv.VideoCapture()
    assert cap.isOpened()

    while not stop_event.is_set():
        (success, frame) = cap.read()
        if not success: break

        ... # do your inference here

        result_queue.put(result_frame)

    cap.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stop_event = threading.Event()
    result_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=1)
    worker_thread = threading.Thread(
        target=worker_function, args=(stop_event, result_queue))
    worker_thread.start()

    cv.namedWindow("window", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    while True:
        # handle new result, if any
        try:
            result_frame = result_queue.get_nowait()
            cv.imshow("window", result_frame)
            result_queue.task_done()
        except queue.Empty:
            pass

        # GUI event processing
        key = cv.waitKey(10)
        if key in (13, 27): # Enter, Escape
            break
    
    stop_event.set()
    worker_thread.join()
```

I didn't test this but the idea is sound.

Comment: great, I would like to display more lively as I could. Can you please edit your answer to display last frame in que, and then delete all previous ones. I don't want all frame captured to be displayed, I focus on live effect.

Comment: If you have issues with the video being delayed, that's due to the camera producing frames independently, at its own fixed rate. since the processing is slower than that, *there* the frames queue up. that's not due to the code I presented. common solutions are to set the buffer size to 0 or 1, or to run another thread that continually reads frames and maintains the latest frame for processing. here's an old piece of code I wrote that handles this: https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/15c3910f243a42dcd9d4a40fcdb24e40